# React server-side fetch (asynchronous rendering)

Tags: reactjs

In short, how can I make this work on the server?

```
import React from 'react';

export default class RemoteText extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {text: null};
        fetch(props.src).then(res => res.text()).then(text => {
            this.setState({text});
        })
    }

    render() {
        if(this.state.text) {
            return <span>{this.state.text}</span>;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Even if I use [isomorphic-fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch), I get this warning:

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounting component. This usually means you called setState() outside componentWillMount() on the server. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the RemoteText component.

Which makes sense. I believe my component has already been rendered to a string by the time the fetch resolves. I need to somehow defer rendering until that's complete, but I don't know how.

Apollo somehow manages this with `getDataFromTree` so I'm sure it's possible.

How can I do the same thing? i.e., walk my component tree, extract all pending fetches and then wait for them to resolve before `ReactDOMServer.renderToString`?

---

Since it doesn't appear to be clear, I would like to reiterate that I want the fetch to happen **server-side** and all the data should be loaded **before** the first render.  The fetches should be co-located with the component (probably via a HOC).

If I can get the data into my Redux store before my `renderToString`, I already have some code to serialize it and pass it down to the client. For reference, I'm rendering my application like this:

```
export default async (req,res) => {
    const rrCtx = {};
    const store = createStore(combineReducers({
        apollo: gqlClient.reducer(),
    }), {}, applyMiddleware(gqlClient.middleware()));

    const Chain = (
        <ApolloProvider store={store} client={gqlClient}>
            <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={rrCtx}>
                <App/>
            </StaticRouter>
        </ApolloProvider>
    );

    await getDataFromTree(Chain); // <--- waits for GraphQL data to resolve before first render -- I wan the same but for fetch()
    const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(Chain);

    if(rrCtx.url) {
        ctx.redirect(rrCtx.url);
    } else {


        const stats = await readJson(`${__dirname}/../webpack/stats.json`);
        const styles = stats.assetsByChunkName.main.filter(f => f.endsWith('.css'));
        const scripts = stats.assetsByChunkName.main.filter(f => f.endsWith('.js'));

        let manifest = {};
        try {
            manifest = await readJson(`${__dirname}/../webpack/manifest.json`);
        } catch(_){}

        if(stats.assetsByChunkName.vendor) {
            styles.unshift(...stats.assetsByChunkName.vendor.filter(f => f.endsWith('.css')));
            scripts.unshift(...stats.assetsByChunkName.vendor.filter(f => f.endsWith('.js')));
        }

        res.send(`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en" />
  <title>RedSpider</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  ${styles.map(f => `<link rel="stylesheet" href="${stats.publicPath}${f}">`).join('\n')}
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/spider.png">
  ${scripts.map(f => `<script src="${stats.publicPath}${f}" defer></script>`).join('\n')}
</head>
<body>
  <div id="react-root">${html}</div>
  <script>
  window.__STATE__=${jsSerialize(store.getState())};
  window.__MANIFEST__=${jsSerialize(manifest)};
  </script>
</body>
</html>`);
    }
}
```

I'm looking for something akin to [react-apollo](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo) but works for arbitrary fetches/GET requests and not just GraphQL queries.

---

Everyone's saying "just `await` it". Await what? The fetch is *inside the component* and the place where I need to await is in a different file. The problem is how do I gather up the fetch-promises such that I *can* await them, and then get that data back into the component?

But nevermind, I'm going to try to reverse engineer [getDataFromTree](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/blob/af2aac22d8e45aa7e3c30630b8cbbec27e30f2c1/src/server.ts#L126) and see if I can get something to work.

Comment: @AndrewLi Not sure how that helps.

Comment: @AndrewLi You're completely missing the point of the question. I want the fetch to happen *server-side*. There will be *no loading phase* because the  *entire component and its data* will be prefetched on the server.

Comment: Yep, I missed the point. Sorry about that.

Comment: I must be missing something, but why not just `await` the fetch before calling `renderToString`?

Comment: @JohnWeisz How? The fetch is in the component, the `renderToString` is in a completely different file. That's the "co-location" challenge. I can fetch the data where I call `renderToString` (not that I want to) but then how do I thread it back into the component?

Comment: @mpen The problem is that, AFAIK, you always need the data to be present _before_ the components are rendered, and this will always require you to await your fetch before calling `renderToString`, one way or another.

Comment: @JohnWeisz Right, and the way Apollo deals with this is to traverse the component tree, gather up the data requirements, and then await them just like I've shown -- `await getDataFromTree(Chain)`. I want to do the same thing but for fetches. Nvm, I'll try to reverse engineer [the function](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/blob/af2aac22d8e45aa7e3c30630b8cbbec27e30f2c1/src/server.ts#L126) and figure out how they get that data into the store.

Comment: @mpen I'm convinced Apollo does something very similar under the hood, as I see no way it can be avoided to ultimately await your fetch before rendering.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `renderToString` from the server, react will call the constructor, componentWillMount and render, then create a string from the rendered element. Since the async operations will be resolved on another tick, you cannot use fetch from componentWillMount or the constructor.

The simpler way to do it (if you don't use any framework/lib that handle that for you) is to resolve fetch *before* calling renderToString.

Comment: Right, and I'm specifically asking *how* can I resolve the fetch before calling `renderToString` (while keeping the fetch co-located w/ the component)? PS: Thank you -- you're the only person who actually understood the question.

Comment: Put your fetch in a static method inside the component, This method will be called twice: once from `componentDidMount` (for client-side) and once from your express route (or whatever you use server-side). After resolving it in the `componentDidMount`, simply `setState` like you currently do. After resolving it in you server route, call `renderToString`, then send the result to the client.

Answer (score 2):

> I believe my component has already been rendered to a string by the time the fetch resolves. I need to somehow defer rendering until that's complete, but I don't know how. [...] I can fetch the data where I call `renderToString` (not that I want to) but then how do I thread it back into the component?

AFAIK, you will always have to `await` any async calls to finish before calling `renderToString` into the response, one way or another.

This problem is not at all uncommon, although this is merely a generic answer, as I use a custom flux implementation instead of Redux. Additionally, this problem is not unique to server-side rendering of a React component tree, as it may just happen that you need to wait on the *client* before you can proceed with rendering into the DOM.

Basically, how I solve this particular problem (whether on the client or server) is the following:

1. simply `await` your `fetch` before calling `renderToString` (as I mentioned, this is virtually unavoidable, as your data *must* exist before proceeding with the response)
2. store the `fetch` results in your store
3. in the component, only initiate a `fetch` for data if that particular data is not yet "preloaded" into your store

In your renderer entry point, simply (although I believe this should be obvious):

```
export default async (req, res) => {
    await fetch().then(res => res.text()).then(text => {
        this.setState({text});
    });

    // Store your data in your store here and instantiate your components.

    const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(Chain);
}
```

In your component:

```
export default class RemoteText extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        // If your store has the data you need, set it directly.
        // Otherwise, call your fetch so that it works on client seamlessly.
    }
}
```

In overall, this will ensure your component works just as well on the client, and has the required data render-ready when prerendering on the server. I'm afraid there is no alternative to `awaiting` your fetch call.

Comment: Awaiting isn't an issue, I'm just trying to figure out how to co-locate the fetch with the component. You've moved the fetch next to `renderToString` -- that's what I'm trying to avoid. That'll be a mess to maintain. I need a way to gather up all the fetch promises, await them all, and then push the results back into the component.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things.

Move your `fetch` request out of the constructor, it does not belong there. `setState()` also does not belong in the constructor.

The `fetch` request and subsequent `setState()` call belong in `componentDidMount()`, not the constructor.

Also, when you make the `setState()` call you are going to want `setState({text: text})` not `setState({text})`. As a side-note, it is idiomatic to forgo blocks for arrow functions that have a single line especially when chaining fetch requests. Likewise placing chained statements on separate lines increases readability. ie:

```
fetch(props.src)
.then(res => res.text())
.then(text => this.setState({text: text}))
```

You can chain `.catch(error => console.log(error));` at the end if you like. Again the important thing to do, is move your `fetch` request and `setState()` call into `componentDidMount()`.

Defining a generic fetch method would be appropriate (especially if there will be more elsewhere); it can take a requestObj, and callback as arguments. You'd call it within in `componentDidMount()`, and anywhere else where fetch requests are made within your app.

In your `render()` call, encapsulate everything you return in a top level div. There is no need to return null in your render call, even when `this.state.text` is null it is still unnecessary. Instead, as you learn React especially at the beginning you're better off always returning a div. In case you haven't seen it before you have the inline operator at your disposal for conditional rendering, it look like this:
    render() {
      const text = this.state.text;

```
  return (
    <div>
      {text &&
        <span>{text}</span>
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Edit: I misunderstood what you are looking to do on first glance. If what you want is for all the data to be loaded before render, pass the data to the component via props. I'm not sure what the structure of your component tree looks like or what you are doing server side but if your not able to pass the data with props alone, pass it to the component via context. To do that you need a higher order component that sets your data to context.
Your existing constructor would then look something like this:

```
constructor(props, context) {

  super(props, context);
  this.state = this.context.text || window.__INITIAL_STATE__ || {text: null};
}
```

Answer (score -2):

As the comments mentioned, do the async operation in `componentWillMount`

```
componentWillMount=()=>{
    fetch(props.src).then(res => res.text()).then(text => {
        this.setState({text});
    })
}
```

Comment: This will not help, as the fetch will be resolved in another tick, the string will already be created at that time.

Comment: Not relevant to the question. Also, [the official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount) say "we recommend using the `constructor()` instead."